# Leaving a RC servo motor idle for long term?

Tags: power, servo

I've been searching for awhile and can't find an answer so hopefully someone here can help me :)

I just want to know if leaving a servo motor idle, powered but no input, is bad for it? I'm planning on leaving a servo motor powered indefinitely and only sending it a signal to move a bit maybe once a day.

I was trying to setup something with a relay so my microcontroller can control the power to the servo but it's a little bit of a pain, not that it can't be done.

So, should I definitely not leave my servo motor powered for days/weeks?
Thanks!

Comment: Note that there is a difference between no signal, and a signal with a steady pulse width.  If you expect the servo to hold position, you really should be providing a signal; behavior without might usually be to hold position, but that isn't really guaranteed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just like any other motor really, if you're running it inside spec it should be fine. Its lifetime isn't indefinite though. I've done a couple of days with no problems.

Comment: Alright, I'll give it a go. It's a crappy "Micro Servo 9g A0090". Came with some stuff I got for my Arduino.